# How Do I Pass Json Object From Fiddler To Webapi2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

http://localhost:15641/api/Complaints/NewComplaint

User-Agent: Fiddler

Content-Type: application/json

Host: localhost:15641

Content-Length: 63

RequestBody
{
"CostCentre":"test","ComplaintText":"This is test Complaint"
}

WebApi Controller

[Route("api/Complaints/NewComplaint")]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void CreateNewComplaint(BLL.Complaint complaint)
    {
        //call BLL Create complaint method
    }


  }
```

my object is with null values 
where am i doing wrong ?
i put breakpoints on controller the complaint object is set with all null values
if i don't pass the values complaint object it self is null
how can i pass the object

Comment: Quotes for property names are ***mandatory*** in JSON. I'd also consider removing the unnecessary carriage returns. So your request body should be `{"CostCentre": "test", "ComplaintText":"djfiojdsifneiorfj  wefnuiwnfjkwe fuwe uiehfuiwf jibui"}` and (if fiddler doesn't do it automatically) adjust the `Content-Length` of your request.

Comment: You may also want to adjust your route name from NewCompalint to the correctly spelled NewComplaint.

Comment: HI Soner i put Quotes for property names in JSON but still the object is filled with null values

Comment: so update your question to show exactly what you're doing so that this omission isn't a distraction to anyone else who wants to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Web API expects the data sent to it to be serialized in a fashion like this:

```
Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2&...
```

If you are using JavaScript or JQuery, make sure that you're sending an Object(in your case matching Bll.Complaint), not a JSON string. If you give us more details on how you execute the request I will update this answer to have an example of how to do the serialization.

Comment: With a header of `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`